# pandas.DataFrame.replace change dtype of columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I was trying to replace `np.nan` values in my dataframe with `None` and noticed that in the process the datatype of the `float` columns in the dataframe changed to `object` even when they don't contain any missing data.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.nan,'B':1.096, 'C':1}, index=[0])
data.replace(to_replace={np.nan:None}, inplace=True)
```

Call to `data.dtypes` before and after the call to `replace` shows that the datatype of column B changed from float to object whereas that of C stayed at int.
If I remove column A from the original data that does not happen.
I was wondering why that changes and how I can avoid this effect.

Comment: @yatu: Why the instant close? The linked answer says nothing about why otherwise unrelated columns see change in their `dtype`; the behavior in OP does not appear if `A` is dropped prior to the replacement.

Comment: Yes ur right, reopened @fuglede

Comment: Looks like a bug - could you report it here? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: Looks buggy to me. Can't see why replacing `NaNs`  should also affect float columns with no missing values. I'd suggest reporting it as @ignoring_gravity suggests if you cannot find related issues

Comment: pure speculation, but I assume that None is treated as a string purely _because_ the `np.nan` value exists, as in there is no clear definition of `None` in a string column or a numeric column, thus its treated as an object by default.

Comment: This appears to already be a known issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23305

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this many times, and there is a fix. precede your usage of your replace with astype(object) and it will preserve the dtypes. I've had to use this for merge issues, combine issues, etc. I'm not sure why it preserves the types when used this way, but it does and it's useful once you find out about it.

```
data.info()    

#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
#Data columns (total 3 columns):
#A    0 non-null float64
#B    1 non-null float64
#C    1 non-null int64
#dtypes: float64(2), int64(1)
#memory usage: 32.0 bytes

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.nan,'B':1.096, 'C':1}, index=[0]) 
data.replace(to_replace={np.nan:None}, inplace=True)                                                                                                                                 

data.info()   

#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
#Data columns (total 3 columns):
#A    0 non-null object
#B    1 non-null object
#C    1 non-null int64
#dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
#memory usage: 32.0+ bytes

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.nan,'B':1.096, 'C':1}, index=[0]) 
data.astype(object).replace(to_replace={np.nan:None}, inplace=True)                                                                                                                  

data.info()                                                                                                                                                                          

#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
#Data columns (total 3 columns):
#A    0 non-null float64
#B    1 non-null float64
#C    1 non-null int64
#dtypes: float64(2), int64(1)
#memory usage: 32.0 bytes
```

Comment: you're not actually setting data in the second example. You simply called .info on the original df

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, when you replace per column, and call `replace` from `pd.Series(...)` rather than from the `pd.DataFrame(...)`.

Except, as mentioned in the comment `NoneType()` cannot be casted to float (or int, or any numeric - you would rather use `NaN` instead), hence it will be automatically casted to `object`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.nan,'B':1.096, 'C':1}, index=[0])
print(data)
print(data.dtypes)
for col in data.columns:
    data[col].replace(to_replace={np.nan: None}, inplace=True)
print(data)
print(data.dtypes)
```

Output:

```py
      A      B  C
0 NaN  1.096  1

A    float64
B    float64
C      int64
dtype: object
      A      B  C
0  None  1.096  1

A     object
B    float64
C      int64
dtype: object
```